# How to configure GithubAuthBackend in Zulip's docker-compose?

Tags: github, docker-compose, zulip

host Zulip and would like to know if someone knows the exact configuration which needs to be done to make the Github Auth Backend works with on-premise GitHub (GitHub.company.com) ?

Will appreciate your suggestion and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure via looking into `settings.py` from the main [zulip repo](https://github.com/zulip/zulip), as well as setting the configuration secrets ex: `SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_KEY`, `SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_ORG_NAME` etc in `zulip-secrets.conf`. Further details are documented in your settings.py.